# What is the correct way to populate a list from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies, firebaseui

From my research, it looks like a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter is the correct way to populate a list of items, but I can't seem to get the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter setup.  I have added the dependencies shown below, but when I try to create the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter the solution says it can't recognize the symbol FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client:2.2.4'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You need to import FirebaseUI*** if you are trying to use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0'
```

Add that to your dependencies and try it again.

Alternatively, if you only want a specific library from FirebaseUI, you can import the specific one:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.6.0'

compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.6.0'

compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
```

Then remember to use:

`import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;`

to each module using it (Android Studio will most likely catch this if you don't)

Comment: Also remove this line, since mixing versions of the Firebase SDK is not a good idea: `    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client:2.2.4'`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added the compile statement and the import statement and I removed the firebase-client dependency, but the import statement doesn't work.  I am getting the error Cannot resolve symbol 'FirebaseRecyclerAdapter'

Comment: Did you re-sync Gradle after adding compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0' ?

Comment: Yes I did.  I also invalidated the cache and restarted Android Studio.

Comment: Would you mind doing a new copy-paste of your dependencies again and add it as an update to your post? Just to see exactly what is being compiled.